# List of lists R, extract lists containing same multiple elements

Tags: r, pattern-matching, nested-lists

I have a list of lists defined in R. It is quite large to manually check so I am making up a small copy to be able to deliver what I want to ask in an efficient manner.

```
>listOfLists
```

```
$CitiesA

$CitiesA[[1]]

[1]Paris

[2]Amsterdam

[3]Istanbul

[4]Vienna



$CitiesB

$CitiesB[[1]]

[1]Amsterdam

[2]Stockholm

[3]Barcelona

[4]Lisbon

[5]Vienna

$CitiesC

$CitiesC[[1]]

[1]Vienna

[2]Budapest

[3]Amsterdam

[4]Paris
```

What I need is to be able extract lists (e.g. `CitiesA` and `CitiesC`) according to multiple patterns they contain (e.g. `Paris` and `Amsterdam`) from the whole list.

I would be able to partition my query into its components (e.g; first extract the ones containing Amsterdam, then Paris, then find the intersect of the results) however, this would get time consuming and hard to implement&read using loops.

I would appreciate if you could let me know of a easier solution.
Here are some examples to what I have tried so far which did NOT give me the correct result;

```
# toMatch <- c(Paris,Amsterdam)
# res <- lapply(listOfLists, function(x)grepexpr(toMatch,x)
# res <- lapply(listOfLists, function(x)match(toMatch,x)
```

I would be glad to keep `listOfLists[['CitiesA']] | listOfLists$CitiesA` subset functionality but if there is a better way of representing this data, I would appreciate your input.

As an output, I would just need the names of the objects containing shared multiple patterns as in;

```
result <- "pseudoCodeToExtractObjects"
names(result)
[1] CitiesA [2] CitiesC
```

And for pattern matching; I am fine with either full pattern matching or a subset of the pattern but since GO terms can be quite similar, I would appreciate if I could match with full queries.

Comment: You say "list of lists", but it looks like a list of vectors. Could you share your sample data in a reproducible way (either the code to create the object or `dput())`?

Comment: Sorry for confusion! That was a subset of my object  Here is a dput() output of a sample object  structure(list(RALYL = list(c("nucleotide binding(GO:0000166)", 
"nucleic acid binding(GO:0003676)", "protein binding(GO:0005515)", 
"identical protein binding(GO:0042802)", "poly(A) RNA binding(GO:0044822)", 
"RNA binding(GO:0003723)")), BNIPL = list(c("protein binding(GO:0005515)", 
"identical protein binding(GO:0042802)")), SCARB2 = list(c("receptor activity(GO:0004872)", 
"virus receptor activity", "protein binding", 
"enzyme binding")),Names = c("RALYL", "BNIPL", 
"SCARB2"))

Comment: Also please provide a sample input and desired result for this object. And please clarify whether matches are identical or *contains*. For example, will a search string be something like "nucleotide binding(GO:0000166)" or might it be a partial string like "GO:000"?

Comment: And, your `dput` is actually a list of lists, but it doesn't appear that it needs to be as each sublist has only a single vector. Would it be possible to simplify to a list of vectors or does your real data actually require nesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. In the future, please work on formatting your question well--it's a real mess--and on making it reproducible.

It appears you have an object like this:

```
# list of lists
lol = list(
    CitiesA = list(c("Paris", "Amsterdam", "Istanbul", "Vienna")),
    CitiesB = list(c("Amsterdam", "Stockholm", "Barcelona", "Lisbon", "Vienna")),
    CitiesC = list(c("Vienna", "Budapest", "Amsterdam", "Paris"))
)
```

But since each sublist only has a single vector, it would be simpler to have an object like this:

```
# list of vectors:
lov = list(
    CitiesA = c("Paris", "Amsterdam", "Istanbul", "Vienna"),
    CitiesB = c("Amsterdam", "Stockholm", "Barcelona", "Lisbon", "Vienna"),
    CitiesC = c("Vienna", "Budapest", "Amsterdam", "Paris")
)
```

(Notice how the structure is clear, anyone can copy/paste this into R and get the same object. Something like this should have been included in your question.)

The differences are whether the outer list contains vectors, or whether the outer list contains inner lists that then contain vectors. The only reason to use a list of lists is if the sub-lists need to contain **multiple** vectors. Your sublists all contain **exactly 1 vector**, so they are pointless.

```
## This is nice
lov$CitiesA
# [1] "Paris"     "Amsterdam" "Istanbul"  "Vienna"   

class(lov$CitiesA)
# [1] "character"

## This is harder to work with
lol$CitiesA
# [[1]]
# [1] "Paris"     "Amsterdam" "Istanbul"  "Vienna"   

class(lol$CitiesA)
# [1] "list"
```

The list of vectors will be easier to work with. Converting a list of lists to a list of vectors is easy:

```
lov2 = lapply(lol, unlist)
identical(lov, lov2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Now to your problem. I think you want to find the vectors in the list that contain *all* of the *exact elements* in some other vector, `toMatch`:

```
toMatch = c("Paris", "Amsterdam")

## We can get the results for each element of the list
lapply(lov, function(x) all(toMatch %in% x))
# $CitiesA
# [1] TRUE
# 
# $CitiesB
# [1] FALSE
# 
# $CitiesC
# [1] TRUE

## or just look at the subset of names that meet the criteria
names(lov)[sapply(lov, function(x) all(toMatch %in% x))]
# [1] "CitiesA" "CitiesC"
```